# How to refresh a parent from a partialview in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a page that shows a collection of objects. For each item in the collection, there is an "Edit" button that loads the details for that item in a partial view (via jquery.load) in a modal. Users make changes in the partial view and save; it all happens within the partial view via ajax. But how do I make those changes show up back in the parent page as well?

I guess I could do `location.reload(true)` etc, but there has to be a better way?.

Comment: you could use a partial view for you collection of objects and only refresh that list of objects

Comment: That depends, do you want to reload the entire page or just the collection?

Comment: Thanks @MihaiTibrea. Duh, I should've thought of that! I'm new to MVC with extensive webforms background, so what would be the simplest thing in the webforms world is beginning to require a complete paradigm shift in the mvc world....specifically, thinking in terms of controllers/actions and multiple forms updating one another has been

Comment: Thanks @ramiramilu, guess putting the collection in it's own partial view solves the problem. I am happy to realod the entire page or the collection, whichever is a better practice for such scenarios.

Comment: Just assign the values from your form controls to javascript variables and if the save was successful, update the values of corresponding row in the DOM. There is no needs to go back to the server. You need to show your view including the scripts - but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) shows a simple example

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, yes updating on the client works best. I was just looking for a quick way to refresh the parent automatically to save the extra time and testing etc needed.